# Navigator.of(context).pop() Give me black screen

Tags: flutter, dart

Noob here.
I've made a update checker with flutter, but if I choose any button, it give me black screen.
How can I fix this? Any ideas?

## **Code**

- Full Source : https://github.com/aroxu/LiteCalculator
- Dialog Part Source :

```dart
import 'package:LiteCalculator/updater/bean/UpdaterBean.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class UpdateHolder extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Version> version;

  UpdateHolder({Key key, this.version}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return calculateResult(
        version[0].latestVersion, version[1].currentVersion, context);
  }

  Widget calculateResult(latestVersion, currentVersion, context) {
    print('Latest Version : ${int.parse(latestVersion)}');
    print('Current Version : ${int.parse(currentVersion)}');
    Widget data;
    if ((int.parse(currentVersion) <= int.parse(latestVersion))) {
      data = Center(
        child: createAlert('Update Required', actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('OK'),
            onPressed: () {
              print('OK Button Pressed.');
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Later'),
            onPressed: () {
              print('Later Button Pressed.');
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
        ]),
      );
    } else
      data = Center();
    return data;
  }

  Widget createAlert(content, {List<Widget> actions, title}) {
    AlertDialog snackBar;
    snackBar = AlertDialog(
      content: Text(content),
      actions: actions,
    );
    return snackBar;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Qonvex620 I just want to make a dialog, and if any button pressed, close itself.

Comment: You are not using dialog. you just displaying an widget in the very first screen. If you do `Navigator.pop` the only screen will be removed from the stack. thats why you are getting black screen.

Comment: @TanzenT what do you except to happen when user presses `OK` and `Later`?

Comment: @CrazyLazyCat I want to if Later button clicked, just close the alertdialog and if OK clicked, open a webpage.

Comment: I'll post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call this for your popup,

```
void showDialogPopup(){
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_)=>AlertDialog(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          content: Container(
          child: Center(
             child: FlatButton(
               onPressed: (){
                 Navigator.of(context).pop(null);
               },
               child: Center(
                 child: Text("close")
               )
             )
           )
          )
        )
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A black screen or a blank screen? If its a black screen, your are not wrapping your main widget (which goes in the runApp) with a MaterialApp.

Comment: As you can see by checking the [repo](https://github.com/TanzenT/LiteCalculator), it's wrapped with MaterialApp.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this.

I used [url_launcher 5.4.1](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) to open PlayStore web.

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: FirstPage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FirstPageState createState() => _FirstPageState();
}

class _FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    _checkUpdate();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> _checkUpdate() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration.zero);
    await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => UpdateDialog(),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text("First Page"),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class UpdateDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UpdateDialogState createState() => _UpdateDialogState();
}

class _UpdateDialogState extends State<UpdateDialog> {
  Future<void> _updateFound;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _updateFound = _checkForUpdate();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<bool> _checkForUpdate() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration.zero);
    bool updateFound = false;
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)); // Do Get call to server
    updateFound = true;
    if (!updateFound) Navigator.pop(context);
    return updateFound;
  }

  Future<void> _openWebPage() async {
    Navigator.pop(context);
    launch("https://play.google.com"); //Your link `url_launcher` package
  }

  void _laterClicked(){
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _updateFound,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
          return AlertDialog(
            content: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                CircularProgressIndicator(),
                const SizedBox(height: 12.0),
                Text("Checking for Update"),
              ],
            ),
          );
        else if (snapshot.hasError)
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text("Error Occured"),
            content: Text("ERROR: ${snapshot.error}"),
          );
        else if(snapshot.data)
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text("Update Required"),
            content: Text(
                "Latest version found. Need an update. bla bla bla bla bla bla"),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text("OK"),
                onPressed: _openWebPage,
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text("LATER"),
                onPressed: _laterClicked,
              ),
            ],
          );
        else
          return const SizedBox();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens whenever you try to `pop` using the Widget's `context`.

In the following code:

```dart
FlatButton(
  child: Text('OK'),
   onPressed: () {
     print('OK Button Pressed.');
     Navigator.of(context).pop();
   },
)
```

`context` represents the context of the widget, itself (provided in the build method).

To resolve this issue instead of creating a Dialog widget and returning it as the main widget, just use `showDialog` and return a simple Container().

Use `dialogContext` to pop the dialog and not the widget itself.

for example:

```dart
 if ((int.parse(currentVersion) <= int.parse(latestVersion))) {
     showDialog(
       builder: (dialogContext) => AlertDialog(
        content: Text('Update Required'),
       actions: <Widget>[
         FlatButton(
            child: Text('OK'),
            onPressed: () {
              print('OK Button Pressed.');
              Navigator.of(dialogContext).pop();
            },
          ),
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Later'),
            onPressed: () {
              print('Later Button Pressed.');
              Navigator.of(dialogContext).pop();
            },
          ),
        ],
     ),
    );
 }
return Container();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and my solution was something like that:

```
bool hasBeenShown = false;
if(!hasBeenShown) {
    Navigator.pop(context);
}
hasBeenShown = true;
```

The problem for me was that for some reason Navigator.pop been invoked multiple times when it's supposed to be invoked only once.